# HTTP Authentication to jetty server from rhino engine

Tags: java, authentication, jetty

I am trying to establish a connection to a web server powered by Jetty. 
The code is running from the Rhino script engine.

The connection looks ok but i get this error, and can get the authentication failure in the log file when I do not put the "Authorization" header. Once i add it, i get the following exception :

```
 Illegal character(s) in message header value: Basic <base64>
```

The code i have is :

```
write2file("Entering doJSON.");
URL = java.net.URL;
HttpURLConnection = java.net.HttpURLConnection;
OutputStream = java.io.OutputStream;
BufferedReader = java.io.BufferedReader;
var url = new URL("http://server-example.com");

Base64 = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
var up = username + ":" + password;
var basicAuth = "Basic " + new java.lang.String(Base64.encodeBase64Chunked(getBytes(up)));

write2file("Basic Auth : " + basicAuth);

var conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

var os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(getBytes(data));
os.flush();

write2file("Response code : " + conn.getResponseCode());

if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
   var br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));
  var output; var ret;
  while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
      ret = ret + output;
  }

   write2file("Response Text : " + ret);
   return -1;
}

var br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(
  (conn.getInputStream())));
var output; var reply;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
   reply = output + reply;
}
write2file(reply);
conn.disconnect();
```

If you have any idea, do not hesitate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does `write2file("Basic Auth : " + basicAuth);` produce in your logfile?

Comment: It is writting the string "Basic Auth : Basic ZnJpbmNbase64kueWtoMg=="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. The issue was nothing to do with the auth, but actually the following line :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content", "application/json");
```

This should have been :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Easy fix, the error was not pointing to right direction.